Passing options (both default and input) to sub-function
I have a function with Options, and I want to pass the Options to a subfunctions, including both Options with default values and Options with input values. For example, I want to pass the Options of func1 to func2:
Options[func1] = {Option1 -> DefaultValue11, Option2 -> DefaultValue12, Option3 -> DefaultValue13};
Options[func2] = {Option1 -> DefaultValue21, Option2 -> DefaultValue22};
func1[x_, opts: OptionsPattern[]] := func2[x, FilterRules[opts, Options[func2]]]
func2[x_, opts: OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue[Option1], OptionValue[Option2]}

In this case, if I run func1[1, Option1 -> InputValue1], then opts will only match the input option Option1 -> InputValue1, hence give:
In[1]:=func1[1, Option1 -> InputValue1]
Out[1]={InputValue1, DefaultValue22}

However, I would like something like opts: OptionsPattern[], but matching {Option1 -> InputValue1, Option2 -> DefaultValue12, Option3 -> DefaultValue13}, thus giving:
In[2]:=func1[1, Option1 -> InputValue1]
Out[2]={InputValue1, DefaultValue12}

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

When you call FilterRules in the definition of func1, just include the default options for func1 after any user-supplied options:
fc[func1[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  func2[x, FilterRules[{opts, Options[func1]}, Options[func2]]]]

which should give the desired behavior:
In[79]:= func1[1, Option1 -> InputValue1]

Out[79]= {InputValue1, DefaultValue12}

In[81]:= func1[1, Option1 -> InputValue1, Option2 -> 13]

Out[81]= {InputValue1, 13}

I encounter this problem whenever making a plotting function:  MyPlotFunction takes all the same options as Graphics, so a user should be able to call SetOptions[MyPlotFunction, ImageSize -> 100].  In my definition of MyPlotFunction then, I need to call Graphics with the correct ImageSize and FilterRules[userSuppliedOptions, Options[Graphics]] doesn't cut it.

So in this case OptionValue[Option1] will always use the first assignment Option1 -> InputValue1 and ignore the following Option1 -> DefaultValue11?

I would probably just do something like this:
func1[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Quiet[func2[x, Options[func1]], OptionValue::nodef]

But you could do a careful merge if you really wanted to. Maybe something like this:
func1[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := func2[x, FilterRules[Normal@Merge[{opts, Options[func1]}, First], Options[func2]]]

